# Routing angular in the same route if the user is logged or not

Tags: angular, routes

so far, for differenciate the pages I had to play around whit the children route, basically if the user is logged the `MainComponent` has to be loaded because in that there is the top bar.
Instead when the user goes to `login` the top bar is not loaded.

I'd like that when the user is logged and he goes to `\` the page loaded would be the `\dashboard` and instead when he is not and he goes to `\` the page loaded would be the `\login` page.

I tried to use the `authguard` but every time that I'm adding `canActivate: [AuthGuard]` my site doesn't work anymore.

my file app-routing.module.ts is :

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
      path: '',
      component: MainComponent,
      children: [
          { path: '', component: DashboardComponent },
          { path: 'missions', component: MissionComponent },
          { path: 'operators', component: OperatorComponent },
          { path: 'materials', component: MaterialComponent },
          { path: 'bins', component: BinComponent },
          { path: 'main', component: MainComponent },
      ]
   },
   { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },

];
```

my auth.guard.ts is :

```
constructor(
    public afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    public userService: UserService,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  canActivate(): Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.userService.getCurrentUser()
      .then(user => {
        //this.router.navigate(['/operator']);
        return resolve(false);
      }, err => {
        return resolve(true);
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: What error do you get? Why the site not working?

Comment: I don't get any error, simply everithing is blank

Comment: Check with chrome. The console.

Comment: You can use enableTracing to get which route is getting loaded with route guard
https://angular.io/api/router/ExtraOptions#enableTracing . It should help to understand whats going on.

Comment: @MaihanNijat already checked, the console is clear..

Comment: See my answer, if it's because of canActivate. That will help if not then it's propably the component you are using. Also, debug it, by putting console.log on canActivate user.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
canActivate() {
  return this.userService.getCurrentUser()
    .pipe(
      tap(user => {
        if (!user) {
          this.router.navigate(['/operator']);
        }
      }),
    );
}
```

If the user is returned, it means it is logged in and if not then it will be redirected where ever you want to redirect.

Comment: Thankyou for your reply, this helped a lot! It was not the solution but I could debug from `console.log`!

Comment: @alessandrobuffoli I am glad you solved your problem.